# Buffered Image Junit error

Tags: java, junit, bufferedimage, ioexception

I get the following error when I try to load a buffered image in a junit test.

Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

The code this affects is:

```
BufferedImage testFrame = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/Darren/testPicture.png"));
```

I have tried surrounding it with try and catch. I get an error stating incorrect syntax when I use try catch.

I have no errors when using buffered image in my main program.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Which specific constructor is this error being attached to? You have at least two object constructions happening in this statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try-catch is the solution here. This example has correct syntax:

```
BufferedImage testFrame;
try {
    testFrame = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/Darren/testPicture.png"));
} catch(IOException e) {
    // do something about it
}
```

The fact that `testFrame` is defined outside the try-catch is very important. If not, `testFrame` will go out of scope after the try block.